# css - list of links with shortened horizontal borders?

Tags: html, css, anchor, html-lists

I'm trying to do something like so:

```
   a link here
   ------------------
   another link here
   ------------------
>> active link here
   ------------------
   one more link
   ------------------
```

where all the `---` are borders but equal lengths. If the current page is the link (i.e. active link) then `>>` display (it'll be an image). The problem is that if I add padding to the `li`s then it'll cause the border to be underneath the `>>` which is not desired. No javascript obviously.

The general markup I've tried to work with is this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">a link here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">another link here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">active link here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">one more link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And what mark-up are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: so use margins instead of padding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest applying the `.active` class to the `li`, rather than the link, and then using:

```
li {
    margin: 0 0 0 5em;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
.active:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: -3em;
    width: 2.5em;
    content: '>>';
    content: url(http://path/to/image.gif);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/psBfA/).

Given the difficulties using the `:before` pseudo-element cross-browser, it seems worthwhile pointing out that `list-style-image` can be used instead:

```
li {
    margin: 0 0 0 5em;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
    position: relative;
}

li.active {
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: circle; // the fall-back option
    list-style-image: url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/bullet_point.gif);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/psBfA/2/).

References:

- [`:before`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after).
- [`list-style-image`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/list-style-image).

Answer (score 0):

You can always change your `a` tags to display block and do something like this to get the border effect you are looking for. Because the border is applied to the `a` element, it shouldn't matter if you apply padding to the `li` or not.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            ul {width: 100px;}
            ul li a {border-bottom: 1px black dashed; display: block;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">a link here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">another link here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">active link here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">one more link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```